# Back Navigation Button Not Showing up in Pushed View Controller

Tags: iphone, uinavigationcontroller, ios4, uinavigationitem

I have a problem where I can successfully push a new view controller from my root view controller (using the Navigation-based application using Core Data template), but the detail view, which is a separate xib file from the root view controller, doesn't display the back navigation button. I'm certain that I've done all of the proper connections in IB, and everything else is working as expected.

RootViewController.h

```
@class ItemsViewController;

@interface RootViewController : UITableViewController <NSFetchedResultsControllerDelegate> {

IBOutlet ItemsViewController *itemsVC;

}

@property (nonatomic, retain) IBOutlet ItemsViewController *itemsVC;

@end
```

RootViewController.m

```
#import "ItemsViewController.h"

@synthesize itemsVC;

- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath 
{
// Pushes to ItemsViewController

ItemsViewController *itemsViewController = [[ItemsViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"ItemsViewController" bundle:[NSBundle mainBundle]];

[self.navigationController pushViewController:itemsViewController animated:YES];
[itemsViewController release];

}
```

ItemsViewController is a UITableViewController subclass with its own xib, also named ItemsViewController. Again, it gets pushed from RootViewController, but the back button doesn't show up [like this.](http://db.tt/av8vzM) I was under the impression that it was a "free" feature of using a navigation controller. As you might expect, this is a very frustrating roadblock and I would appreciate any help.

Comment: I had the same issue until seeing this post. That is really weird default behavior. Why not just "Back" if no title is provided?

Comment: Yeah that, or some kind of error or warning in Xcode would be nice.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Does your `ItemsViewController` class set its `title` property in its `viewDidLoad` method?

You should call `[tableView deselectRowAtIndexPath:indexPath animated:YES]` as the last line of `tableView:didSelectRowAtIndexPath:` to conform to Apple's human interface guidelines.

Comment: I haven't set the title yet. Its going to come from a CD name property that one enters from the RVC. Does the title need to be set for the back button to appear?

Comment: True. But you should always have a title on the nav bar. How about this: are you setting the `title` in `RootViewController`'s `viewDidLoad` method? I've had problems before with the back button when the root view's title wasn't set.

Comment: Excuse me while I pick my face up from the desk. Setting a title in the RVC gave me the back button. I guess it needs to be populated before it renders. Thanks for the tip, I won't be forgetting that anytime soon!

Comment: Even more strange is that it does appear in the simulator!

Answer (score 10):

Yeah, make sure you have a title on your RootViewController, if it doesn't no button will appear.  To set a title programmatically;

```
self.navigationItem.title = @"Hello Der";
```

Answer (score 1):

Some extra info for future readers: I ran into this problem while trying to re-populate a nav hierarchy on application load, so I was calling setViewControllers: from the app delegate's application:didFinishLaunchingWithOptions: method. And I was running into the same problem with the back button not showing up.

In my case, setting the root view controller's nav item title in its viewDidLoad did not work, presumably because the other views were loading first and seeing the root's title as null. Instead, I set the root view controller's nav item title in my application:didFinishLaunchingWithOptions: method right before I called setViewControllers:, and that fixed it.

Answer (score 0):

Try following snippet. It work for me!

```
[self.navigationController.navigationBar setBackgroundImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"Image.png"] forBarMetrics:UIBarMetricsDefault];

[self.navigationController.navigationBar bringSubviewToFront:[self.navigationController.navigationItem backBarButtonItem]];
```

Answer (score 0):

This can also happen if you're a bonehead and mistakenly initialize the view as modal instead of pushing a view to the navigation controller.

oops: [self presentModalViewController:navController animated:YES];
meant: [self.navigationController pushViewController:controller animated:YES];